# Why performance decline when try to mark one million marker in google map using javascript API?

Tags: google-maps

it give  very poor performance by using the all possibilities in javascript API. In Flash it is possible using one open source algorithm.  Is there any solution to increase the performance ?

Can SVG give some solution to this?

Answer (score 0):

You have a map with 1 million markers on it, and you're surprised at poor performance?  You could try clustering your markers.  Alternatively, only plot those that would be visible in the current bounds.  Each time the bounds change, replot them.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think SVG is the solution, it's vector-based and gives poor performance for many objects. Canvas would be much better compared to SVG.

If you must use 1.000.000 markers either user server-side clustering or experiment using Canvas if possible.